# How to resize imageView according to images from gallery in swift

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller

I am placing imageView in view..

**containerView constraints**

```
   top = 40, leading = 0, trailing = 0, height = 180
```

**imageView constraints with containerView**

```
  top = 0, leading = 0, trailing = 0, bottom = 0
```

i am getting images from gallery code: i am using imagepicker for images

```
class FinalViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var profileImg: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var picContainerView: UIView!

var picker = UIImagePickerController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    picker.delegate = self
}


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden=true
}
@IBAction func profileButton(_ sender: Any) {
       let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
       actionSheetController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.picContainerView
       let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
       }
       actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
       let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "TakePhoto", style: .default) { action -> Void in
           self.openCameraPicker()
       }
       actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)
       let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "ChooseFromLibrary", style: .default) { action -> Void in
           self.openPhotoGallery()
       }
       actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)
       //Present the
       self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)
   }
      
          func openCameraPicker() {
            picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
            picker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            picker.allowsEditing = true
            picker.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            present(picker,animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
        func openPhotoGallery() {
            picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
            picker.allowsEditing = true

            picker.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
            present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        // MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate Methods
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let img = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage{
                profileImg.image = img
            }
            else if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.profileImg.image = image
            }
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
      }
```

**if i give `AspectFit`** then o/p.. image along with empty spaces

[image]

**if i give `AspectFill`** then o/p.. image stretches

[image]

how to resize imageview according to image. please help me with code

Comment: You force the size of the container and you force the imageView to be the size off container. How do you expect to adjust ? Try change container constraint into height ≥ 100

Comment: @claude31 okay i did height greatthen or equal to.. but not much change

Comment: if i have given wrong constraints.. then please do let me know.. i need to make image to fit in the imageView

Answer (score 0):

First try to set the background of the ContainerView to clear and not to white.
if this doesn't work try this:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];

CGFloat width = img.size.width;
CGFloat height = img.size.height;
```

then set the ImageView's hight and width to the ContainerViews width and hight.